# What does it mean if a mutating function setting it's self equals to another function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I was going through Apple's Arkit project sample. I was trying to understand the code since, I am still learning. I saw a function setting it self equals to another function can someone please explain what these functions are exactly doing. Please brief in detail.In the code the "mutating func normalize()" is setting it self to self.normalized why is it. What this code is doing. Can we not simply call "func normalized()" seems like we are re-creating the same function.

```
mutating func normalize() {

   self = self.normalized()
}


func normalized() -> SCNVector3 {

    if self.length() == 0 {
      return self
  }
    return self / self.length()
}



func length() -> CGFloat {

    return sqrt(self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y)

    }
```

Comment: Higher Order functions, take a look on https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/higher-order-functions-in-swift-filter-map-reduce-flatmap-1837646a63e8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this fragment is in a `struct` rather than a class.

`self.normalized()` makes a copy of `self` and divides the copy's components by its length and then returns the copy. `self` is not affected.

`self.normalize()` gets a normalised version of `self` and then replaces `self` by the copy. So it changes in place.

Under the hood, every member function passes `self` as an implicit argument. i.e. to the compiler the declaration looks like this:

```
func normalised(self: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3
```

Putting `mutating` on the front of a function definition makes the hidden argument `inout`

```
func normalise(self: inout SCNVector3)
```

So, if you have

```
var a = SCNVector3(3, 4, 0)
let b = SCNVector3(4, 3, 0)
let c = b.normalized() 
a.normalize()
```

After that code, `c` would be `(0.8, 0.6, 0)` and `a` would be `(0.6, 0.8, 0)`. `b` would be unchanged.

Note that `a` has to be declared with `var` because it is changed in place by `normalise()`

**Edit**

In the comments khan asks:

> What i am not able to understand is why do we have to create a func again we can use "func normalized"

The point being made is why can't we do something like this:

```
    var a = SCNVector3(3, 4, 0)
    a = a.normalized()
```

and not have the `normalise()` function at all?

The above will have exactly the same effect as `a.normalize()` and, in my opinion[1], is better style, being more "functional".

I think `a.normalize()` exists only because it is common in Swift to provide both forms of the function. For example, with sets you have both `union()` and `formUnion()`: the first returns the union of one set with another, the second replaces a set with the union of itself and another set. In some cases, the in place version of the function may be more efficient, but not, I think, with this `normalize` function.

Which you choose to use is a matter of your preference.

---

[1] Actually, the better style is

```
let a = SCNVector3(3, 4, 0).normalized()
```

Comment: its not a struct, It's under extension for SCNVector3

Comment: self.normalized() makes a copy of self and divides the copy's components by its length and then returns the copy. "self is not affected" <===== this is the self if and only if length == 0 because then only its unaffected else the copy will be divided by length. Am i right ?

self.normalize() gets a normalised version of self and then replaces self by the copy. So it changes in place. <==== And here i think we are taking about the mutating function ?

Comment: @khan `SCNVector3` is a struct.

Comment: @khan re: your second comment yes, everything you say in it is correct.

Comment: point is still valid.. What i am not able to understand is why do we have to create a func again we can use "func normalized" on a too... or may be in my understanding they want to make another function same like normalized but inout. but still if you can explain a bit more will be very thankful.

Comment: @khan updated the answer. Hopefully it is a bit clearer. And you are right, it is a bit pointless in this case having both functions.

Answer (score 1):

Values types in Swift can be mutable and immutable . So when you create struct( or any other value type) and assign it to variable (var) it is mutable and you call normalize() on it. It means that struct won’t be copied to another peace of memory and will be updated in place (will act like reference type). But when you assign it to constant (let) - it can’t be mutated so the only way to update values in this struct is to create new one with updated values as with normalized() method. Regarding your question - normalize() is just reusing logic for normalizing vector from normalized(). So this is completely fine solution. Assigning to self is only permitted in mutable methods. It’s basically rewrites value of struct with new one.